# How to call API for authenticate user in swagger

Tags: api, authentication, swagger

I've created some API for my application, all the APIs are for the authenticate user except one which is used to make user authenticate.

I am maintaining all the APIs in swagger. Everything working fine. I am calling the first API to make user authenticate

www.example.com/endpoint/registerDevice I got the expected result but when I called the second API and got the result as error message you are not the authenticate user then I realized that swagger is not persisted the session cookie.

Is there any way to make all the API working in swagger?

I am using swagger 2.0 and I've hosted swagger on my server.

Comment: This question could be improved.  For example, "I am using swagger 2.0."  What exactly to you mean?  Are you using Swagger UI?  Are you using a Swagger generated client library?

Comment: Yes, I am using swagger UI, As I said I have some APIs in which I called the first API for making user authenticate and when I called the second API it said you are not authenticated in fact I was already authenticated in my first API call so Is this a bug in the swagger that he is not maintaining the session cookie or am I missing something?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think Swagger UI maintains the session cookie.  That would be done by the browser.  Are you sure your API is returning a Set-Cookie header?  I have tested a similar scenario with Swagger UI.  I know API requests from Swagger UI include all relevant cookies.  So it worked well for me, but I'm not an expert in Swagger UI.

Comment: Yes I've checked my API in POSTMAN chrome extension it set the session cookie in my browser but when I call it via swagger UI it doesn't.